# Concatenação de string em SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, string, varchar, concatenação-de-string

Realizo uma consulta numa tabela na minha base de dados MySQL que me retorna os seguintes campos: `usuarioId` `nome` `sobrenome` `idade` `sexo` `escolaridade` `modeloNome` `hora`

Segue o sql abaixo:

```sql
SELECT 
    sv_users.userID as `usuarioId`,
    sv_users.userNome as `nome`,
    sv_users.userSobrenome as `sobrenome`, 
    sv_users.userDataNascimento as `idade`, 
    sv_users.userSexo as `sexo`, 
    sv_users.userEscolaridade as `escolaridade`, 
    sv_modelos.modelNome as `modeloNome`,
    sv_jogo.`Data` as `hora`    
FROM sv_jogo      
   INNER JOIN sv_users ON sv_jogo.UsuarioId = sv_users.userID
   INNER JOIN sv_modelos ON sv_users.userModelId = sv_modelos.modelId
WHERE 
   (sv_users.userNome LIKE 'Luitame%' OR sv_users.userSobrenome LIKE 'Luitame%') 
OR 
   (sv_users.userNome LIKE '%Luitame' OR sv_users.userSobrenome LIKE '%Luitame') 
OR 
   (sv_users.userNome = 'Luitame' OR sv_users.userSobrenome = 'Luitame')
```

Até aqui tudo tranquilo, me retorna o esperando. Como abaixo: 
[image: tabela de dados]

Só que além de poder consultar campo à campo e comparar o conteúdo. Eu queria que fosse possível realizar uma consulta por nome completo ou somente uma parte do nome completo. Exemplo: "Luitame de Oliveira" e a consulta me retorne algum registro, pois seguindo a consulta acima ele só me retorna algum valor se eu buscar pelo `nome` ou `sobrenome`. Mas, se eu fizer a junção de `nome + sobrenome` a consulta não me retorna nada.

Como no exemplo abaixo:

```sql
SELECT 
    sv_users.userID as `usuarioId`,
    sv_users.userNome as `nome`,
    sv_users.userSobrenome as `sobrenome`, 
    sv_users.userDataNascimento as `idade`, 
    sv_users.userSexo as `sexo`, 
    sv_users.userEscolaridade as `escolaridade`, 
    sv_modelos.modelNome as `modeloNome`,
    sv_jogo.`Data` as `hora` 
FROM sv_jogo 
    INNER JOIN sv_users ON sv_jogo.UsuarioId = sv_users.userID
    INNER JOIN sv_modelos ON sv_users.userModelId = sv_modelos.modelId
WHERE 
    (sv_users.userNome LIKE 'Luitame de Oliveira%' OR sv_users.userSobrenome LIKE 'Luitame de Oliveira%') 
OR 
    (sv_users.userNome LIKE '%Luitame de Oliveira' OR sv_users.userSobrenome LIKE '%Luitame de Oliveira') 
OR 
    (sv_users.userNome = 'Luitame de Oliveira' OR sv_users.userSobrenome = 'Luitame de Oliveira')
```

Confiram o resultado:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguma sugestão?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Você está buscando por capacidades de [full-text search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html) (que, desde o MySQL 5.6.4 [também funcionam com InnoDB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-table-and-index.html#innodb-fulltext-index)).

```sql
ALTER TABLE sv_users ADD FULLTEXT INDEX (userNome, userSobrenome);
```

E para a consulta:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM sv_users
WHERE MATCH (userNome, userSobrenome) 
AGAINST ('Luitame de Oliveira' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Se as facilidades do MySQL não forem suficientes (geralmente não são) você pode usar uma ferramenta externa como o [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/), [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/) ou [Elasticsearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/). Essa ferramentas possuem facilidades que deixam [as consultas booleanas](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-boolean.html) e em [linguagem natural](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-natural-language.html) do MySQL no chinelo, podendo tratar abreviações, sinônimos, erros de ortografia, palavras similares, etc. Além disso, são muito mais robustas quando o número de consultas cresce.

---

**UPDATE**:

Exemplos demonstrando meu ponto sobre a versão do MySQL e suporte à Full Text Search no InnoDB.

Demo I: [SQL Fiddle - MySQL 5.5 (MyISAM)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0b0f0/19)
Demo II: [SQL Fiddle - MySQL 5.6 (MyISAM e InnoDB)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fee97/4)

Eu não queria entrar nesse nível de talhe na resposta, mas como o @Kenny fez uma consulta sem usar o [Boolean Mode](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-boolean.html) é importante notar que, mesmo sem operadores especiais, essa opção faz diferença caso você utilize a *engine* MyISAM (e eu conservei meus hábitos dessa época). Com o *Boolean Mode*  espaços agem como o operador `OU` (e você pode construir consultas similares ao Google com `+`, `-`, etc). No caso de InnoDB as duas consultas voltam o mesmo resultado caso você não utilize um operador especial, mas ainda é interessante ser utilizado para evitar a [a regra de exclusão dos 50%](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3283706/how-to-disable-mysqls-match-querys-50-exclusion) (não deve ser relevante no seu caso a não ser que mais de 50% dos seus usuários se chamem Maria ou João, mas é bom saber saber caso você indexe alguma palavra muito popular).

Comment: É isso que dá: `[Err] 1214 - The used table type doesn't support FULLTEXT indexes`

Comment: Luitame, você deve estar usando uma tabela InnoDB em uma versão anterior ao MySQL 5.6.4. Atualize seu MySQL. Para testes (não recomendado) você pode alterar a engine da tabela para MyISAM: `ALTER TABLE sv_users ENGINE = MYISAM;`, mas em produção não vale a pena a não ser que você saiba o que você esteja fazendo.

Answer (score 7):

Tente isto:

```sql
    SELECT 
    sv_users.userID as `usuarioId`,
    sv_users.userNome as `nome`,
    sv_users.userSobrenome as `sobrenome`, 
    CONCAT_WS(` `, `nome`, `sobrenome`) as nome_completo,
    sv_users.userDataNascimento as `idade`, 
    sv_users.userSexo as `sexo`, 
    sv_users.userEscolaridade as `escolaridade`, 
    sv_modelos.modelNome as `modeloNome`,
    sv_jogo.`Data` as `hora` 
FROM sv_jogo 
    INNER JOIN sv_users ON sv_jogo.UsuarioId = sv_users.userID
    INNER JOIN sv_modelos ON sv_users.userModelId = sv_modelos.modelId
WHERE 
    (nome_completo LIKE 'Luitame de Oliveira%') 
OR 
    (nome_completo LIKE '%Luitame de Oliveira') 
OR 
    (nome_completo = 'Luitame de Oliveira')
```

**Caso o volume de dados for muito grande e seja necessário uma melhor performance, você pode utilizar o `Fulltext`, da seguinte forma:**

```sql
ALTER TABLE sv_users ADD FULLTEXT INDEX (userNome, userSobrenome);
```

A consulta ficaria da seguinte forma:

```sql
    SELECT 
    sv_users.userID as `usuarioId`,
    sv_users.userNome as `nome`,
    sv_users.userSobrenome as `sobrenome`, 
    sv_users.userDataNascimento as `idade`, 
    sv_users.userSexo as `sexo`, 
    sv_users.userEscolaridade as `escolaridade`, 
    sv_modelos.modelNome as `modeloNome`,
    sv_jogo.`Data` as `hora` 
FROM sv_jogo 
    INNER JOIN sv_users ON sv_jogo.UsuarioId = sv_users.userID
    INNER JOIN sv_modelos ON sv_users.userModelId = sv_modelos.modelId
WHERE 
    MATCH(sv_users.userNome, sv_users.userSobrenome) AGAINST("Luitame de Oliveira")
```

Comment: Resolve o problema, mas fique atento a performance!

Comment: Se começar a pesar na performance, utilize buscas com `Fulltext` -> [Documentação e exemplos](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-natural-language.html)

Comment: Obrigado pelas sugestões, fiz as devidas modificações!!!

Comment: Como se não bastasse o MySQL retorna um erro dizendo que a tabela utilizada não suporta o FULLtext. Vejam: `[Err] 1214 - The used table type doesn't support FULLTEXT indexes`

Comment: Ainda não conseguir rodar está dando isso seguindo seu exemplo! `[Err] 1054 - Unknown column 'nome' in 'where clause'` o FULLtext eu já resolvi!!!

Comment: O amigo Kenny tentou usar *aliases* no match, o que infelizmente não é suportado; use `WHERE MATCH (userNome, userSobrenome)` como no meu exemplo.

Comment: Alterei isto, acho que agora ta redondo!

Comment: Opa. Não se esquece de aceitar a resposta do Kenny ou a minha. Outra dica, se você resolveu o problema do *full text* alterando a engine para MyISAM faça o *upgrade* do banco do MySQL para uma versão mais nova (conforme as demos abaixo) e use a *engine* InnoDB. Não vale a pena abdicar do suporte a transações e usar uma *engine* que volta e meia corrompe o DB só para ter acesso a funcionalidades de *full text search*. MyISAM é uma *engine* legada que está sofrendo uma morte lenta desde a versão 5.5 do MySQL. Como o Falcon caiu no limbo, o futuro está no MariaDB e as *engines* Aria e XtraDB.

Comment: Obrigado eu percebi que ele não estava aceitando o aliases e fiz as alterações aqui! Obrigado pela força e farei o recomendado! @AnthonyAccioly

Answer (score 1):

Como já foi dito, pode usar um `Full-Text Index`. No StackOverflow em inglês, expliquei como utilize essa índice no MySQL. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18492876/sql-specific-statement-query/18492997#18492997

Answer (score 0):

O problema me parece ser devido ao fato de que o primeiro nome ("Luitame") está em uma coluna ("userNome") e o restante do nome ("de Oliveira") em outra coluna (userSobrenome). Sendo assim, procurar pelo nome completo em uma das colunas não vai mesmo produzir resultados.

Além disso, como o nome completo está separado em duas colunas, é necessário lembrar que **não há** o espaço entre "Luitame" e "de Oliveira".

Eu não tenho como testar aqui neste momento, mas talvez este teste funcione:

```sql
SELECT 
    sv_users.userID as `usuarioId`,
    sv_users.userNome as `nome`,
    sv_users.userSobrenome as `sobrenome`, 
    sv_users.userDataNascimento as `idade`, 
    sv_users.userSexo as `sexo`, 
    sv_users.userEscolaridade as `escolaridade`, 
    sv_modelos.modelNome as `modeloNome`,
    sv_jogo.`Data` as `hora` 
FROM sv_jogo 
    INNER JOIN sv_users ON sv_jogo.UsuarioId = sv_users.userID
    INNER JOIN sv_modelos ON sv_users.userModelId = sv_modelos.modelId
WHERE 
    concat(concat(sv_users.userNome, ' '),sv_users.userSobrenome), LIKE '%Luitame de Oliveira'
```

Comment: Não consegui rodar seu exemplo! Dá este erro: `[Err] 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 14
`

Comment: Desculpe, acho que tem um parântese a mais no começo da linha 14. De todas as formas, vc já tem respostas melhores. :)